# How can I fake multiple inheritance?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, viewmodel, multiple-inheritance

I know that multiple inheritance is impossible then how can I get all the data that I need. Is there a way to "fake" multiple inheritance, or what is a better option?

This is what I have, in my LoanProperties.aspx page:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<LoanManager.Models.VW_FIELD_VALUE>"
```

and I also need

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<LoanManager.Models.Loan>"
```

Sorry if I didnt provide enough information I'm fairly new to this, if more is needed I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new class that contains a property for Loan and a property for VM_FIELD_VALUE both
In your view you can then do Model.Field and Model.Loan

However its wrong to call it faking multiple inheritance. It would be composition.

Comment: thank you for correcting me, i was unsure what to call it, and thx for the help, im going to try this and post my results if i can or cant get it to work